# "Source file found twice" error with mypy>=0.780 in python for vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mypy, vscode-python

In my python project, after upgrading `mypy` from 0.770 to 0.782 an error is received in files where there were previously no type errors:

```
my_pkg_name\__init__.py: error: Source file found twice under different module names: 'top_pkg.my_pkg_name' and 'my_pkg_name'
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I'm pretty sure this is related to [Issue #8944](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8944) on mypy and the way which vscode-python executes mypy on the open files. I've tried adding various mypy flags (e.g. `--namespace-packages`, `--no-namespace-packages`) but this did not resolve the issue.

`my_pkg_name` **does** contain an `__init__.py` and so does `top_pkg`. With `mypy==0.770` this was not a problem.

Looking at the extension's output this is how mypy is invoked:

```
> ~\.virtualenvs\OfflineSystem.38\Scripts\python.exe `
   c:\Users\***\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.108011\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py mypy `
   --ignore-missing-imports --follow-imports=silent --show-column-numbers `
   d:\***\top_pkg\my_pkg_name\sub_pkg\my_file.py
```

Should change something in the mypy-related vscode settings for this to work?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had a similar issue, but not via VSCode. The fix in my case was to remove an `__init__.py` file from a directory that was being included by adding it to the MYPYPATH, and so wasn't actually being treated as a module (so it shouldn't really have had the `__init__.py` file).

You said you tried adding the `--namespace-packages` flag, but I think you would need `--no-namespace-packages` to disable the new checker which might be causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks @dshepherd, unfortunately the `--no-namespace-packages` did not work either in my case. The exact same issue persists. I'll try and see if the new information you're giving here can help me out in any way and will post a solution if I find one.

Comment: remove __init__.py from root directory worked for me.

Comment: `--no-namespace-packages` worked for me. (Who can just delete their package's root `__init__.py` without consequence?)

Comment: Much better answer than the original issue and the maintainer's message via link.

Answer (score 4):

For me `--explicit-package-bases` worked.

From mypy documentation

> This flag tells mypy that top-level packages will be based in either
> the current directory, or a member of the MYPYPATH environment
> variable or mypy_path config option. This option is only useful in in
> the absence of **init**.py. See Mapping file paths to modules for
> details

Answer (score 3):

In my case adding an `__init__.py` helped as it was missing from the particular module.